# Networking Woes

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, modem, iptv

My set-up is quite complex for me. I have a telephone line, broadband and IPTV on a single line. The service provider gave me a wireless modem (I am not sure if that is the correct term - the telephone line goes in and the internet is working). For IPTV, a LAN cable comes out of the modem (from any 1 of the 4 ports provided at the back of the modem) and goes into a set-top box.

Until recently, it was all working fine. However, given the poor range of my original modem, my younger brother installed a new modem along with the previous one - one on top of the other. The new modem increased the range significantly. The new modem does not have any telephone line port. It only has 5 LAN ports. The first one, which is placed significantly apart from the others, is labeled WAN; while the remaining ones are labeled LAN 1 through LAN 4.

When I bought the second TV, I wanted a parallel connection and hence requested my service provider for the same. What they did was gave me a parallel LAN cable wire to the new tv location. One end would go into the one of the three free ports at the back of my original modem. The second end was free. Whenever I needed to watch the TV on another TV, I would simply disconnect the Lan cable from my set-top box at the first TV point, and connect it to the new point in the other room.

Unfortunately, I had to relocate. The new house is considerably large, and as a result, neither of the modem is sufficient to cover the entire house. I tried a similar setup, but with a little tweaking. Since the modem coverage is not sufficient, i decided to put the two modem in two different rooms. What I did was, the original modem stays in the drawing room along with TV 1, and from there, I drew a parallel lan cable to my master bedroom where I have placed TV 2.

The problem is - Only one thing works. Either the set top box will work in my bedroom, or the modem. The set-top box does not have any Lan-Out port. The second modem has. If i insert the LAN cable directly to my set top box, it works. But if insert it in my second modem and connect the set top box using a separate LAN cable (connecting it to one of the free LAN ports at the back of the modem)- while the internet works both in wireless as well as wired mode, the IPTV does not. It simply says network disconnected. There are no issues in the drawing room. It works perfectly there.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you confirm that *nothing* is connected to the new router's WAN port? (Since it's not connected to a WAN.) And can you confirm that you disabled the DHCP server in that router? (You don't want two DHCP servers on the same LAN.)

Answer (score 2):

Your second modem is actually a router. Simplified a router is a device that allows to connect a local network (LAN) with the internet (WAN). A router is made to share one internet connection with several computers but can not distribute an iptv signal. Therefore you have to decide if you want to use TV in your bedroom or internet. If you want both you need another cable.